# Delegate declaration

Tags: c#

Hi
I have summarized my problem in following code snippet.
In the first code i have declared a delegate and event in the same class while in  **Code 2** i have declared delegate and event in separate class.

**Code 1**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        delegate void Greeting(string s);
        event Greeting myEvent;
        void OnFire(string s)
        {
            if (myEvent != null)
                myEvent(s);

        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program obj = new Program();
            obj.myEvent += new Greeting(obj_myEvent);
            obj.OnFire("World");
        }

        static void obj_myEvent(string s)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello " + s + "!");
        }
    }
}
```

**code 2**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DelegateDemo obj = new DelegateDemo();
            obj.myEvent+=new DelegateDemo.Greeting(obj_myEvent);
            obj.OnFire("World");
        }

        static void obj_myEvent(string s)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello "+s +"!");
        }
    }
}
```

**DelegateDemo.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class DelegateDemo
    {
       public delegate void Greeting(string s);
       public event Greeting myEvent;
       public void OnFire(string s)
        {
            if (myEvent != null)
                myEvent(s);

        }
    }
}
```

Now i have one question.Is there any diffrence (like thread safe ,performance)  between these two code snippets?

Comment: @Andreas:Like thread safety,performance.

Comment: Other than a few things are defined in different classes?

Comment: So far, both seem to do the same. What exactly is your question?

Comment: Well, the code doesn't address thread safety explicitly at all, so I'd say that they don't differ on that count.

Comment: @santosh: if you are after performance you could easily do a benchmark yourself

Comment: @Markus:I know both do the same but my question is that what is the diff between these two code in terms of thread safety or performance

Comment: None, as far as I can see, as both do exactly the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference seems to be the use of a separate class. So no: as long as the methods and types are accessible there is very little functional difference.

As a side note, you may want to consider `Action<string>` for a delegate that takes a `string` and returns `void`, but also note that events should *generally* follow the `(object sender, SomeEventArgsClass e)` pattern (where `SomeEventArgsClass:EventArgs`, perhaps also using `EventHandler<T>`)

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is no difference, but you should define delegates outside of classes since a delegate IS a class (deriving from from Delegate).